# How to position text in a navigation "div."

Tags: css, html

OK. Thank you for giving me your precious time to look over this problem.

Basically, I have a "div" which I use at the top of the screen for my navigation bar. It's a simple navigation bar, just a 80% wide "div" with some text that changes color on hover.

The problem that I'm having is; the text automatically starts at the top of the "div" and I'd like to center it. I've tried margins, paddings, floats, "div's" inside "div's" etc. etc.

I will post the code here for the navigation bar and if you happen to know how to fix it can you please let me know?

Thanks

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="header">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Repairs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tune up/ Viruses</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">System Builds</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cables</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Find us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
               <!-- <li><a href="/"><img src="facebook.png"></a></li>   -->
            </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.header ul { margin:0px;}
        div.header
        {
            width: 80%;
            height: 40px;
            margin-top: none;
            margin-bottom: none;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            border-top: none;
            border-left: none;
            border-right: none;
            border-bottom: none;
            background-color:  #575757;
        }
        li
        {
            display: inline;
            font-family: 'open sans,' arial;
            padding-right: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        li a 
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
        }
        li a:hover
        {
            color: #00ccff;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a bunch of things to vertically center an element.

The best one for one line elements (elements with just one line of text, for example) is `line-height`

Set the `line-height` to be equal the height of its parent:

```
li { line-height: 40px; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your speedy and accurate response. It is exactly what I needed. As a "junior" 16 year old coder who is still learning about HTML and CSS I rely on good natured people like you who know the answers and are happy to provide them to others.

Just one more thing, will this work on all content types e.g. images?

Thank you.